# How to use Html.TextBoxFor for submodels - get name attribute correct

Tags: asp.net-mvc

We have several forms that ask our Members for personal information. We have a single model for personal information and a partial view to consume that model. Several models use the PersonalInfo model as a submodel.

I want the partial view to be able to render html with the correct name attribute. For correct binding, the name attribute for the FirstName input tag should be "PersonalInfo.FirstName" - not "FirstName".

I want to use Html.TextBoxFor because it takes advantage of the Data Annotations and unobtrusive validation. Html.TextBox does not implement validation for the Data Annotations.

OR - maybe someone can tell me why Html.TextBox does not use the Data Annotations and create client side validation.

```
public class PersonalInfo {
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "First Name is required")]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "First Name must be less than 50 letters")]
    public string FirstName {get; set;}
    public string LastName {get; set;}
}

public class MemberModel {
    public string ShoeSize {get; set;}
    public PersonalInfo PersonalInfo {get; set;}
}

public class VolunteerModel {
    public string HairColor {get;set;}
    public PersonalInfo PersonalInfo {get; set;}
}
```

Member View:

```
@model Member
using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    <h1>Member Info</h1>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.ShoeSize)
    @{Html.RenderPartial("_PersonalInfo", Model.PersonalInfo);}
}
```

Volunteer View:

```
@model Volunteer
using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    <h1>Volunteer Info</h1>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.HairColor)
    @{Html.RenderPartial("_PersonalInfo", Model.PersonalInfo);}
}
```

Partial View For Personal Info ... _PersonalInfo.cshtml:

```
@model PersonalInfo
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.FirstName)
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.LastName)
```

Controller:

```
public class MemberController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(new MemberModel());
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(MemberModel model)
    {
        // model.PersonalInfo.FirstName should be set from user input at this point.
        // It is not set correctly when <input name="FirstName">.
        // It will work if <input name="PersonalInfo.FirstName">.
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

Html Code rendered by partial view:

```
<input class="basic-textbox focus" data-val="true" data-val-length="First Name must be less than 50 letters" data-val-length-max="50" data-val-required="First Name is required" id="FirstName" name="FirstName" type="text" value="Joseph" />
```

If I use Html.TextBox, I don't get client-side validation.

```
@Html.TextBox("PersonEditorModel.FirstName", Model.FirstName)
```

results in:

```
<input id="PersonEditorModel_FirstName" name="PersonEditorModel.FirstName" type="text" value="Joseph" />
```

Comment: You want to use TextBoxFor (without partials so the Model can 'see' the hierarchy) or use editor templates

Comment: Dave - I believe I want to use the partials so I don't have to repeat TextBoxFor(FirstName) and TextBoxFor(LastName) in all of the forms that use the partial. Maybe I didn't understand you ...

Comment: You half understood me. To bind hierarchically, you should either use TextBoxFor(m=>m.PersonEditorModel.FirstName or use Editor Templates http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2011/09/07/building-forms-for-deep-view-model-graphs-in-asp-net-mvc/

Answer (score 2):

You should use EditorTemplates instead of partial views.

You need to move `_PersonalInfo.cshtml` to `Views\Shared\EditorTemplates\PersonalInfo.cshtml` and change Volunteer View:

```
@model Volunteer
using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    <h1>Volunteer Info</h1>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.HairColor)
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.PersonalInfo) @* << change *@
}
```

See [the blogpost mentioned by Dave A](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2011/09/07/building-forms-for-deep-view-model-graphs-in-asp-net-mvc/) for more details. There is also a [recent article](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETMVCDisplayTemplateAndEditorTemplatesForEntityFrameworkDbGeographySpatialTypes.aspx) by Scott Hanselman showing EditorTemplates.